# Do Opportunity Products (OpportunityLineItems) count against storage limit?

Tags: limits, opportunity-lineitem, data-storage

I am bit confused about whether Opportunity Products count against storage limits or not? We have a lot of Opportunity Products in our system but in the storage tab, we do not see Opportunity Products.

The Salesforce storage guide (http://sforce.co/1pz5B0e) doesn't mention Opportunity Products but neither does it say that it is excluded. Another link (http://bit.ly/1y2U7nl) mentions that Opportunity Products are not counted towards the limit but I am not sure of the authenticity of the data.

Is there a Salesforce documentation which specifically mentions that Opportunity Products are not counted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opportunity line items do not count against storage quotas. Anything that does use storage space would be listed on the Storage Usage page in your org, and also would be listed on the Storage Usage help topic linked in the original question. If opportunity line items did consume space, that document page would explicitly call out that fact. One important rule to remember regarding salesforce.com documentation is that anything not mentioned doesn't exist or doesn't apply. Omissions in the documentation are always intentional.

Comment: by induction, one could then assume that QuoteItem and OrderItem don't count against storage either.  and furthermore, an excellent reason to use OOTB SFDC objects where possible in lieu of custom object alternatives.

Comment: @cropredy Sadly, Quote Line Items do have a cost, which seems kind of arbitrary. It's always worth checking setup to see what costs and what's free.

Comment: hmm -- fyi - I stumbled upon this answer when realizing that OrderItem and Asset were "free" from a storage point of view. A big deal in our org with over 1MM of ea.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find comprehensive documentation for this, but I did an experiment on some objects to see whether they count toward the org data storage limit or not. Here are my findings:

**Counts against storage:**

- Quote Line Item
- Case Team Member

**Does not count against storage**

- OpportunityLineItem
- OrderItem
- AccountTeamMember
- OpportunityTeamMember
- OpportunityContactRole
- CaseContactRole

Comment: Good callout re: Quote Line Item. This is not mentioned explicitly in Data and Storage Allocations (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.overview_storage.htm&type=5) and yet it definitely counts against storage.